# Adding New Entry at bottom of StringGrid in C++ Builder at run time

Tags: c++builder, stringgrid

I want to add new entries generated by logs at run time from my software  at the bottom of StringGrid widget (20 rows and 2 columns) in  C++ Builder 5.

Whether there is any Property of StringGrid widget which can automatically delete entry in top most row before adding new entry in bottom most row in case all rows of fixed size StringGrid is occupied with data.

Please inform me if you need any other information from me.

Many thanks

Saurabh Jain

Answer (score 3):

As I [told you in the Embarcadero forums](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/programming-languages/f/c-language/72006/adding-new-entry-at-bottom-of-stringgrid-in-c-builder-at-run-time)...

There is no **public** property/method for what you are asking for.  You will just have to set/increment the `RowCount` property as needed, then manually shift up the contents of the `Cells` property, and then finally fill in the bottom row.

```cpp
if (StringGrid1->RowCount < SomeMaxValue)
    StringGrid1->RowCount = StringGrid1->RowCount + 1;

for(int row = 1; row < StringGrid1->RowCount; ++row)
{
    for(int col; col < StringGrid1->ColCount; ++col)
    {
        StringGrid1->Cells[col][row-1] = StringGrid1->Cells[col][row];
    }
}

// fill in StringGrid1->Cells[...][StringGrid1->RowCount-1] for the last row as needed...
```

However, `TStringGrid` does have a **protected** `DeleteRow()` method, but being protected, you need to use an accessor class to reach it, eg:

```cpp
class TStringGridAccess : public TStringGrid
{
public:
    void RemoveRow(int row) { TStringGrid::DeleteRow(row); }
};

if (StringGrid1->RowCount > 0)
    ((TStringGridAccess*)StringGrid1)->RemoveRow(0);

StringGrid1->RowCount = StringGrid1->RowCount + 1;
for(int row = 1; row < StringGrid1->RowCount; ++row)
{
    for(int col; col < StringGrid1->ColCount; ++col)
    {
        StringGrid1->Cells[col][row-1] = StringGrid1->Cells[col][row];
    }
}

// fill in StringGrid1->Cells[...][StringGrid1->RowCount-1] for the last row as needed...
```

That said, `TStringGrid` is really not the best choice for what you are trying to do.  I would strongly suggest using `TListView` in `vsReport` mode instead.  That is what I use in my log viewer, and it works very well, especially in virtual mode (`OwnerData=true`), and it just looks more natural than `TStringGrid`, since `TListview` is a wrapper for a native Windows control whereas `TStringGrid` is not.

```cpp
if (ListView1->Items->Count > 0)
    ListView1->Items->Items[0]->Delete();

TListItem *Item = ListView1->Items->Add();
// fill in Item->Caption (column 0) and Item->SubItems (columns 1+) as needed...
```

Comment: Many many thanks @Remy Lebeau for your reply. I will try to use ListView in my application as suggested by you..!!